# Selecting count from another table is only showing 1 row where it exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select a row count from another table even if it's empty, so if it's empty it just shows the number 0 but still selects the main table's rows.

Here's my sql:

```
SELECT training.*, 
    count(distinct training_transactions.training_transaction_course) as completed_training_payments 
    FROM training
    INNER JOIN training_transactions
         ON training.course_id = training_transactions.training_transaction_course
    WHERE course_main = ?
        AND course_enabled = 'enabled'
```

Training table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `training` (
  `course_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `course_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `course_main` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `course_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_description` text NOT NULL,
  `course_location` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_duration` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_fitness_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_instructor_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_price` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `course_start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `course_max_attendees` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `course_accommodation` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_accommodation_price` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_status` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `course_enabled` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'enabled',
  `course_location_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_location_street` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_location_town` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_location_county` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_location_postcode` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `course_location_country` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `training`
--

INSERT INTO `training` (`course_id`, `course_user`, `course_main`, `course_type`, `course_name`, `course_description`, `course_location`, `course_duration`, `course_fitness_type`, `course_instructor_name`, `course_price`, `course_start_date`, `course_max_attendees`, `course_accommodation`, `course_accommodation_price`, `course_status`, `course_enabled`, `course_location_name`, `course_location_street`, `course_location_town`, `course_location_county`, `course_location_postcode`, `course_location_country`) VALUES
(1, 3, 4, 'Health & Safety', 'lol', 'This is just a short description, this can be editted', '1', '13', 'lol', 'lol', 5, '1991-02-12', 4, '1', '4', 'live', 'enabled', '', '', '', '', '', 'United Kingdom'),
(2, 3, 4, 'Working at Height', 'lol', '', '1', '11', 'jkjkj', 'kjkjkj', 124, '0000-00-00', 6, '0', '', 'live', 'enabled', '', '123', '123', '123', 'WN8', 'United Kingdom'),
(3, 3, 4, 'Working at Height', 'lol', '', '1', '11', 'jkjkj', 'kjkjkj', 124, '0000-00-00', 6, '0', '', 'live', 'enabled', '', '123', '123', '123', 'WN8', 'United Kingdom');
```

training_transactions

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `training_transactions` (
  `training_transaction_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `training_transaction_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `training_transaction_course` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `training_transaction_status` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pending',
  `training_transaction_payment_status` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `training_transaction_cost` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `training_transaction_enabled` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'enabled',
  `training_transaction_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `training_transaction_billing_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `training_transaction_billing_address1` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `training_transaction_billing_address2` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `training_transaction_billing_city` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `training_transaction_billing_state` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `training_transaction_billing_postcode` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `training_transaction_billing_country` varchar(250) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `training_transactions`
--

INSERT INTO `training_transactions` (`training_transaction_id`, `training_transaction_user`, `training_transaction_course`, `training_transaction_status`, `training_transaction_payment_status`, `training_transaction_cost`, `training_transaction_enabled`, `training_transaction_date`, `training_transaction_billing_name`, `training_transaction_billing_address1`, `training_transaction_billing_address2`, `training_transaction_billing_city`, `training_transaction_billing_state`, `training_transaction_billing_postcode`, `training_transaction_billing_country`) VALUES
(1, 3, 1, 'pending', 'complete', 0, 'enabled', '2015-09-17 14:02:29', *removed my address*);
```

at the moment only the training course with id 1 is showing because a row in transactions exists how can I make all training display if it no id matches in the training_transactions?

Comment: change `INNER JOIN training_transactions` to `LEFT JOIN training_transactions` http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: you're also missing a `group by` clause...

Comment: Left join still shows the same results.

Comment: Marc, that fixed it. Thanks, any idea why?

Comment: Adding a group by will result in a query that may or may not run on mysql depending on the configuration of mysql, and is likely to fail in most rdbms, so the code will not be portable. You need a subquery to do this properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LEFT JOIN instead of inner join to list all records from the table on the left of the join, plus you need to place the count() in a subquery to get all fields from the training table:

```
SELECT training.*, ifnull(T.transactioncount,0) as transactioncount
    FROM training
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT training_transaction_course, COUNT(training_transaction_course) as transactioncount FROM training_transactions GROUP BY training_transaction_course) AS T
         ON training.course_id = T.training_transaction_course
    WHERE course_main = ?
        AND course_enabled = 'enabled'
```

Answer (score 0):

INNER JOIN only selects records where records with join key in both tables exist.

With LEFT JOIN / RIGHT JOIN, selections can be made where records on one side don't exist; their field values will be NULL (and when counted, they should be zero but I'm not COMPLETELY sure of that)

Comment: I've tried left join, 1 row is still only being show when it should show them all

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is just easier to use sub-queries. Try this:

```
SELECT training.*, 
    (SELECT COUNT(distinct training_transactions.training_transaction_course)
     FROM training_transactions
     WHERE training.course_id = training_transactions.training_transaction_course) AS completed_training_payments 
FROM training
WHERE training.course_main = ?
  AND training.course_enabled = 'enabled'
```

Comment: This would run a subquery for each record in the trainings table, so this would not scale well.